# Unexpected CASE (T_CASE)

Tags: php

Ok pessoal, eu realmente to perdido aqui, eu to com um erro de case e não tenho ideia de como resolver o código estou colocando abaixo, desde já obrigado.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'case' (T_CASE) in
> /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/joy_theme/single.php on line 370
>
> line 370 case 'blog': ( and if i remove the error comes to next
> line)
>  line 371 case '':

```
<?php get_header(); require('keys.php'); ?>
<!-- breadcrumb -->
<div class="breadcrumb">
    <?php seobreadcrumbs();?>
    
    <span style="float:right; margin:-15px 0 0 0;"><?php edit_post_link('Editar');?></span>
</div>
<!-- fim breadcrumb -->

<div class="doble-dote" style="margin:0 0 20px 0;"></div>


<!-- esquerda -->
<div class="esquerda">

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    setPostViews($post->ID);
    /* ----  TIPO POST  ---- */
    $tipo_post = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tipo_post', true);

    if($tipo_post == 'video') {
        /* ----  THUMBNAIL  ---- */
        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'post_capa');
    
        
        /* ----  INFO VIDEO  ---- */
        $esconder_capa_video = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'esconder_capa_video', true);
        $capa = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'capa', true);
        $tempo = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tempo', true);
        $lancamento = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'lancamento', true);
        $audio = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'audio', true);
        $trailer = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'trailer', true);
        $esconder_trailer = get_post_meta($post->ID,'esconder_trailer_rodape', true);
        
        /* ----  DOWN LINKS  ---- */
        $esconder_download = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'esconder_lista_download', true);
        $servidor_download = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'servidor_download', true);
        
        
        /* ----  VIDEO EMBEDS  ---- */
        $esconder_assistir = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'esconder_lista_assistir', true);
        $servidor_assistir = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'servidor_assistir', true);
    }
?>


<?php switch($tipo_post) {
    case 'video': ?>
    
    <!--
    /* ---------------------------------------------------------
        /   VIDEO   /
    --------------------------------------------------------- */
    -->
    
    <article>
    <!-- videos servidores -->
    <div class="tabs">   
        <!-- embed videos -->
        <div class="embeds-servidores">
        <?php
        if(is_array($servidor_assistir)) {
        $i = 1; foreach ($servidor_assistir as $embed) {
            
            if($embed != '') {
            
            echo '<div class="embeds-video">';
            echo do_shortcode($embed);
            echo '</div>';
            $i++;
            
            }
        }
        }
        ?>
        </div>
        <!-- fim embed videos -->
        
        <?php if($esconder_assistir != 1) {?>
        <!-- title -->
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <?php if(is_array($servidor_assistir)) {?>
        <span class="assistir-title play-ico open-sans">
            Assistir Filme
        </span>
        <?php }?>
        <!-- fim title -->
        
       
        <div class="clear"></div>
       
        <!-- links servidores -->
        <ul class="links-servidores">
        <?php 
        if(is_array($servidor_assistir)) {
        $i = 1; foreach ($servidor_assistir as $servidor) {
            
            if($servidor != '') {
            
            if($i==1) {
            echo '<li class="active">';    
            } else {
            echo '<li>';    
            }
            echo '<span name="tabs-'.$i.'" class="link-servidor pfregular block">Assistir Server '.$i.'<span class="arrow-assistir"></span></span>';
            echo '</li>';
            $i++;
            
            }
        }
        }
        ?>
        </ul>
        <!-- fim links servidores -->
        <?php }?>
    </div>
    <!-- fim videos servidores -->
    
    <?php if(is_array($servidor_assistir)) {?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="doble-dote" style="margin:0 0 15px 0;"></div>
    <?php }?>
    
    
    <?php if($esconder_download != 1) {?>
    <!-- baixar links -->
    <div class="baixar-links">
       <!-- title -->
       <?php if(is_array($servidor_download)) {?>
       <span class="assistir-title down-ico open-sans">
       BAIXAR FILME
       </span>
       <?php }?>
       <!-- fim title -->
       
       <div class="clear"></div>
       
       <!-- links download -->
       <ul class="links-servidores download-lista">
       <?php
        if(is_array($servidor_download)) {
        $i = 1; 
        foreach ($servidor_download as $servidor) {
            if($servidor != '') {
            
            $url = $servidor;
            $parse = parse_url($url);
            
            echo '<li class="tooltip2" title="'.$parse['host'].'">';    
            echo '<a href="'.$servidor.'" target="_blank"><span name="tabs-'.$i.'" class="link-servidor pfregular block">Servidor '.$i.'<span class="arrow-assistir"></span></span></a>';
            echo '</li>';
    
            $i++;
            
            }
        }
        } 
        ?>
        </ul> 
        <!-- fim links download -->
    </div>
    <!-- links baixar -->
    
    
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="doble-dote" style="margin:30px 0 10px 0;"></div>
    <?php }?>
    
    <!-- infos video -->
    <?php if($tempo) {?>
    <span class="info-video open-sans tempo-video">
        <strong>Tempo:</strong> <?php echo $tempo;?>
    </span>
    <?php }?>
    
    <?php if($lancamento) {?>
    <span class="info-video open-sans lancamento-video">
        <strong>Lançamento:</strong> <?php echo $lancamento;?>
    </span>
    <?php }?>
    
    <?php if($audio) {?>
    <span class="info-video open-sans audio-video">
        <strong>Áudio:</strong> <?php echo $audio;?>
    </span>
    <?php }?>
    
    <span class="info-video open-sans visitas-video">
        <strong>Visitas:</strong> <?php echo getPostViews(get_the_ID());?>
    </span>
    <!-- infos video -->
    
    
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="doble-dote" style="margin:10px 0 15px 0;"></div>
    
    
    <?php if($esconder_capa_video != 1) {?>
    <!-- capa single -->
    <div class="capa-single">
        <img src="<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) { echo $thumbnail[0]; } elseif($capa) { echo $capa;} else {?><?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/capa.jpg<?php }?>" alt="<?php the_title();?>" />
    </div>
    <!-- fim capa single -->
    <?php }?>
    
    <!-- content single -->
    <div class="content content-single">
        <?php the_content();?>
    </div>
    <!-- fim content single -->
    
    
    <?php /* mostar compartilhamento */ if($mostrar_compartilhamento == 'true') {?>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="doble-dote" style="margin:15px 0 15px 0;"></div>
        
        <span style="float:left; margin:0 10px 0 0;">
        Compartilhar Post: 
        </span>
        
        <?php if($mostrar_facebook_share == 'true') {?>
        <span style="float:left; margin:0 10px 0 0;">
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php the_permalink();?>" data-width="110" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="false" data-send="false"></div>
        </span>
        <?php }?>
        
        <?php if($mostrar_twitter_share == 'true') {?>
        <span style="float:left; margin:0 10px 0 0;">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="<?php the_title();?>" data-via="<?php echo $twitter;?>" data-lang="pt">Tweetar</a>
        </span>
        <?php }?>
        
        <?php if($mostrar_google_share == 'true') {?>
        <span style="float:left; margin:0 10px 0 0;">
        <g:plusone size="medium" href="<?php the_permalink();?>"></g:plusone>
        </span>
        <?php }?>
    
    <?php }?>
    
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="doble-dote" style="margin:15px 0 10px 0;"></div>
    
    <!-- infos video -->
    <span class="info-video open-sans categoria-video">
        <strong>Categorias:</strong> <?php the_category(', ');?>
    </span>
    
    <span class="info-video open-sans tag-video">
        <?php the_tags('<strong>Tags:</strong> ', ', ');?>
    </span>
    <!-- infos video -->
    </article>
    
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="doble-dote" style="margin:10px 0 35px 0;"></div>
    
    
    <!-- relacionados -->
    <div <?php if($esconder_trailer != 1 && $trailer) { echo 'class="coll-relacionados-trailer"';}?>>
        <span class="assistir-title open-sans" style="border-bottom:1px solid #2f2f2f; padding:0 0 5px 0px; margin:0 0 15px 0; display:block;">
            <span class="relacionados-icon"></span>RELACIONADOS
        </span>
    
    
        <!-- relacionados lista -->
        <div class="flexslider <?php if($esconder_trailer != 1 && $trailer) { echo 'slider-relacionados'; } else { echo 'slider-relacionados-full'; }?>">
        <?php 
        $orig_post = $post;
        global $post;
        $categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
        
        if ($categories) {
            $category_ids = array();
            foreach($categories as $individual_category) $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;
        
            $args=array(
                'category__in' => $category_ids,
                'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
                'posts_per_page'=> 10, 
                'caller_get_posts'=>1,
                'orderby' => 'rand',
                'meta_key' => 'tipo_post',
                'meta_value' => 'video',
            );
        
            $my_query = new wp_query( $args );
            if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                $i=0;
                echo '<ul class="slides lista-filmes" style="background:none;">';
                while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                    $my_query->the_post();
                    
                    $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'post_capa');
                    $capa = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'capa', true);
                    ?>
        <li style=" <?php if($esconder_trailer != 1 && $trailer) { echo 'margin:0 10px 0 0;'; } else { echo 'margin:0 15px 0 0;'; }?> ">
            <!-- titulo box -->
            <div class="titulo-box open-sans">
                <h2 class="titulo-box-link">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" title="<?php the_title();?>" <?php if (strlen($post->post_title) > 21) {echo 'class="tooltip"'; }?>><?php if (strlen($post->post_title) > 21) {echo substr(the_title($before = '', $after = '', FALSE), 0, 21) . '...'; } else {the_title();} ?></a>
                </h2>
            </div>
            <!-- fim titulo box -->
            
            <div class="clear"></div>
            
            <!-- capa -->
            <div class="capa">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="absolute-capa no-text"><?php the_title();?></a>
            <img src="<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) { echo $thumbnail[0]; } elseif($capa) { echo $capa;} else {?><?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/capa.jpg<?php }?>" alt="<?php the_title();?>" />
            </div>
            <!-- fim capa -->
            
            <div class="clear"></div>
            
            <!-- views -->
            <div class="views">
            <?php echo getPostViews(get_the_ID());?> visitas
            </div>
            <!-- fim views -->
            
            <!-- balao comentario -->
            <div class="balao-comentario">
            <?php comments_popup_link('0','1', '%', '','-'); ?>
            </div>
            <!-- fim balao comentario -->
            
        </li>
        <? $i++;
            }
                echo '</ul>';
            }
        }
        $post = $orig_post;
        wp_reset_query(); 
        ?>
        </div>
        <!-- relacionados lista -->
    </div>
    <!-- fim relacionados -->
    
    
    
    <?php if($esconder_trailer != 1 && $trailer) {?>
    <!-- trailer -->
    <div class="coll-relacionados-trailer" style="float:right;">
    
        <span class="assistir-title trailer-ico open-sans" style="border-bottom:1px solid #2f2f2f; padding:0 0 5px 30px; margin:0 0 15px 0; display:block;">
        Trailer
        </span>
    
        <!-- embed trailer -->
        <div class="embed-trailer">
        <?php echo stripslashes($trailer);?>
        </div>
        <!-- fim embed trailer -->
    
    </div>
    <!-- fim trailer -->
    <?php }?>
<!--
/* ---------------------------------------------------------
    /    FIM VÍDEO   /
--------------------------------------------------------- */
-->
    
    <?php break;
    case 'blog':
    case '': ?>
    
    <!-- content blog -->
    <div class="content content-blog">
    <?php the_content();?>
    </div>    
    <!-- fim content blog -->
    
    <?php /* mostar compartilhamento */ if($mostrar_compartilhamento == 'true') {?>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="doble-dote" style="margin:15px 0 15px 0;"></div>
        
        <span style="float:left; margin:0 10px 0 0;">
        Compartilhar Post: 
        </span>
        
        <?php if($mostrar_facebook_share == 'true') {?>
        <span style="float:left; margin:0 10px 0 0;">
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php the_permalink();?>" data-width="110" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="false" data-send="false"></div>
        </span>
        <?php }?>
        
        <?php if($mostrar_twitter_share == 'true') {?>
        <span style="float:left; margin:0 10px 0 0;">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="<?php the_title();?>" data-via="<?php echo $twitter;?>" data-lang="pt">Tweetar</a>
        </span>
        <?php }?>
        
        <?php if($mostrar_google_share == 'true') {?>
        <span style="float:left; margin:0 10px 0 0;">
        <g:plusone size="medium" href="<?php the_permalink();?>"></g:plusone>
        </span>
        <?php }?>
    
    <?php }?>
    
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="doble-dote" style="margin:15px 0 10px 0;"></div>
    
    <!-- infos video -->
    <span class="info-video open-sans categoria-video">
        <strong>Categorias:</strong> <?php the_category(', ');?>
    </span>
    
    <span class="info-video open-sans tag-video">
        <?php the_tags('<strong>Tags:</strong> ', ', ');?>
    </span>
    <!-- infos video -->
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="doble-dote" style="margin:10px 0 35px 0;"></div>
    
        
    <?php break;
}?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<div class="clear"></div>

<!-- comentarios -->
<div class="comentarios">
    <?php comments_template();?>
</div>
<!-- fim comentarios -->


<?php else : endif; ?>
    
</div>
<!-- fim esquerda -->


<!-- direita -->
<div class="direita">
<?php require('sidebar.php');?>
</div>
<!-- fim direita -->

<?php get_footer();?>
```

Comment: A linha 370 seria qual? poderia colocar ela em destaque?

Comment: eu especifiquei no tópico a linha 370 é "case 'blog':"

Comment: Pelo seu comentário, talvez seja uma chave de fechamento que esteja no lugar errado

Comment: Com essa indentação vai ser um pouco difícil de encontrar o fecha chaves sobrando. (mas aí é culpa da forma que o wordpress trabalha...)

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que isso:

```
case 'blog':
case '':
```

não funciona assim.
Se o seu objetivo é definir que a opção 'blog' é a padrão caso não seja informada uma opção, use o método **default**, assim:

```
case 'blog':
default:
    // seu código aqui
    break;
```

teoricamente, o **default** é a ultima opção do *switch*, então nem precisaria usar o `break;` mas pode usar se quiser.

Comment: Nem sei como não reparei nisso..

Comment: Walter eu entendi o que tu disse, porém o erro tá na linha case 'blog' ela é inesperada logo algo antes disso poderia está fazendo acontecer este erro, não? eu já fiz as alterações com o default e ainda sim persiste os erros, primeiro fala que o endwhile é inesperado depois o else e por fim 'fim de código inesperado', ainda estou na tentativa aqui kkk, se eu conseguir algum resultado eu comento!